# My friends can't connect to my Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

People can't connect to my server minecraft over internet (just lan).
I installed the server and disabled the firewall. I think the problem is the port 25565 (which I already opened). I have been read a lot but anything works, please help

Comment: You might want to hide your public IP address. Some trolls here may try to DDoS you.

Answer (score 2):

For Anyone who needs the solution: I installed Hamachi and now my brother and friends (not lan) can join to my server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port number.

Try putting `:25565` after the server IP (in the MC client).

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't work, thanks for the answer

Comment: @user270015 does it work if you replace the IP with your local IP? (that is, enter `192.168.18.14:25565`)

Comment: @user270015 just to confirm, if you go to https://whatsmyip.com/, it gives you 167.250.55.170? (if not try whatever it gives you)

Comment: @user270015 Okay. Then I'm not sure. Make sure you and your brother both are allowing the connection through your firewall / internet setting; if that's done, then sorry, I'm not sure what error you're getting.

Comment: firewall is disable, but thank you for your time my friend ♥